# Where can I find a social network image dataset?

Tags: dataset

I am supervising a programming project whose goal is to detect offensive images on social networks. 
I would like to have a representative dataset of social network images. It would be best if the dataset were already classified. Otherwise, the classification of a (smallish) dataset could be a part of the project.

I looked around the internet and searched various dataset collections that are freely available, but I haven't been able to find anything appropriate.

What is the best way to get a large social network image dataset these days?

Comment: Recently I have been a part of similar project to classify offensive images for one of a project. I have the model ready and trained. But dataset is not open. May be I can use the model to create a small classified dataset for you.
please let me know.

Comment: Sounds good! Can I contact you directly? My email is zluria@gmail.com.

Comment: Aside from your question, isn't this a type of positive-unlabelled classification problem as `not offensive` is not exactly a category, how are you solving it? as going for a binary classification doesn't seem intuitive to me

Comment: That's true. I think that if I can go over the raw data, I could get a sense of which categories of offensiveness are more common, and then train a classifier to recognize them.

Answer (score 2):

Google just released a beta search tool for datasets. This can help you find any kind of datasets you want: https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch

Answer (score 1):

Most social networks such as Instagram have Terms of Service prohibiting *crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos*, check https://www.kaggle.com/general/23419 for a discussion of the matter.

Likely you will need to scrap it yourself (there are scripts out there doing it for you) but you will not find a ready to download dataset.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe that would be the best practical solution, but I'm not sure that I want to place myself on the wrong side of the law. I guess I could have my students manually scrap a few thousand images to create a small dataset.

Comment: @ZurLuria Can be good to teach your students how to scrape data instead of collecting it by hand. It is often a core part of many data science projects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they are relevant, but found various image data set which can be categorized as offensive vs non-offensive image, based upon your selection criterion.

Links are:

1. https://github.com/EBazarov/nsfw_data_source_urls
2. https://github.com/alex000kim/nsfw_data_scraper

Both the links categorized thousand's of file as per they characteristics and include URL's of the image.

Based upon your criteria you marked particular text file images as offensive/non-offensive. Just you have to write small code to download these files and set the label accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Something like this could be a good solution, but I am worried that a collection of porn images on the one hand, and neutral images of objects on the other, is very far from a representative sample of images from social networks.

Comment: Also, offensive images aren't necessarily sexual images. If an image contains drugs, violence or other criminal activity, it should also be classified as offensive...

Comment: True, but it has n number of categories and based upon your preference you can list offensive/non-offensive image.